# TP Link T4U adapter not showing up in router's DHCP clients list

Tags: networking, wireless, dhcp, tp-link

I connected a TP Link Archer T4U (FCC ID: TE7T4UV3) to my Ubuntu Server 20.04, and then installed the cilynx/rtl88x2bu driver module following the [instructions](https://github.com/cilynx/rtl88x2bu/blob/48e7c19c92a77554403e1347447f8e2cfd780228/README.md#dkms-installation) in the README.  VER is 5.6.1. I see a new adapter called `wlx9848273269cd` in `ip link show`.

I added my WiFi network SSID and password into `/etc/netplan/00-installer-config.yaml` using the new TP Link T4U's adapter name:

```
wifis:
  wlx9848273269cd:
    access-points:
      myssid:
        password: s3cr3t
    dhcp4: true
    optional: true
```

I then ran `sudo netplan apply` which completed successfully.

When I run `ip link show` I see

```
6: wlx9848273269cd: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 12:34:56:78:90:ab brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

However when I log in to my router and view the DHCP Clients List, there is no new entry for this device. I see other WiFi devices like my laptop in the DHCP Clients List, and I see an entry corresponding to the ethernet adapter mac address of the same Ubuntu Server (which appeared automatically with no manual configuration).

If I run `sudo iw dev wlx9848273269cd scan | grep "SSID: myssid"`, I see my WiFi network SSID in the output.

What can I do to make my TP Link T4U show up in the router's DHCP Clients List and connect to my WiFi network?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to connect to WiFi interactively using `nmtui`.

```
sudo apt install network-manager
sudo nmtui
```

and then using the UI to select my SSID, enter its password, and activate.